# Wordpress >> Using different CSS for differnet pages

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have having an issue with the following code :

```
<!--CSS files -->
<?php

function my_styles_method() {
    // Register the style like this for a theme:  
    wp_register_style('my-custom-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/includes/front-page.css');
    // enqueue the stule  
    wp_enqueue_style('my-custom-style');
    // Register the style like this for a theme:  
    if (is_page_template('our-story.php')) {
        wp_register_style('my-custom-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/includes/main.css');
        // enqueue the stule  
        wp_enqueue_style('my-custom-style');
    }
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_styles_method');
?>
```

I am using the page template our-story.php and using the function as specified here :http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags but somehow the main.css file doesn't get loaded. When I comment out the code for the front-page.css file and remove conditional statements than main.css files loaded and works correctly but not within this condition. I am not sure if I am using it correctly.

Looking forward to your response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you use the body classes ? http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class

You can target whatever page / template you want with those classes. Ex:

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

On the homepage will give you :

```
<body class="home page page-id-14 page-template page-template-home-php ">
```

So, if you want specific CSS for homepage :

```
.home { Your styles }
```

Comment: will try it out and let you know how it goes

Answer (score -1):

I think may use this.

```
if(is_page( 42 )) // id, title or slug name
```